# How to merge results of two mysql tables in one output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two similar mysql tables and want to get the data from both of them in one output (merge). How can I do it?

For this reason I have created two separate queries to check that I get what I'm looking for.

First: Table -> web_session

```
SELECT date_format(booking_time, '%m-%Y') AS m, count(booking_time) AS b
FROM web_session
WHERE
  date(booking_time) >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 12 month)
AND
  date(booking_time) <= date_add(curdate(), interval 6 month)
GROUP BY month(booking_time)
ORDER BY booking_time ASC;
```

Output:

```
m, b
10-2013, 15
11-2013, 6
12-2013, 13
01-2014, 10
02-2014, 10
03-2014, 25
04-2014, 1
```

Second: Table -> web_log

```
SELECT date_format(request_time, '%m-%Y') AS m, count(request_time) AS r
FROM web_log
WHERE
  date(request_time) >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 12 month)
AND
  date(request_time) <= date_add(curdate(), interval 6 month)
GROUP BY month(request_time)
ORDER BY request_time ASC;
```

Output:

```
m, r
03-2014, 45
04-2014, 35
```

**desired output:**

```
m, b, r
10-2013, 15, null
11-2013, 6,  null
12-2013, 13, null
01-2014, 10, null
02-2014, 10, null
03-2014, 25, 45
04-2014, 1,  35
```

Comment: You use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join them. Try this:

```
SELECT T1.m,T1.b,T2.r FROM
(
SELECT date_format(booking_time, '%m-%Y') AS m, count(booking_time) AS b
FROM web_session
WHERE
  date(booking_time) >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 12 month)
AND
  date(booking_time) <= date_add(curdate(), interval 6 month)
GROUP BY month(booking_time)
ORDER BY booking_time ASC;) T1

LEFT OUTER JOIN

(SELECT date_format(request_time, '%m-%Y') AS m, count(request_time) AS r
FROM web_log
WHERE
  date(request_time) >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 12 month)
AND
  date(request_time) <= date_add(curdate(), interval 6 month)
GROUP BY month(request_time)
ORDER BY request_time ASC;) T2

ON T1.m=T2.m
ORDER BY T1.m
```

Output will be:

```
m          b      r
10-2013    15     null
11-2013    6      null
12-2013    13     null
01-2014    10     null
02-2014    10     null
03-2014    25     45
04-2014    1      35
```